# Where to get GLEXT.h?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-c++

How can I get the glext.h header file?  Am I supposed to make my own glext.h file and paste all the code from the Khronos OpenGL Registry into it? Also, I'm using Windows and have the SDK, is glext supposed to be in my GL folder? Because I checked it and it's not.

Currently I've tried to find a download on the internet with no luck.

Comment: I recommend using GLEW instead of this. Operating systems haven't included proper OpenGL headers since forever; they made it your problem to access all the OpenGL bits instead of the operating system's, but you should use GLEW or something like it to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just wondering for a little side project that I've been working on. This is my only problem currently and It's been causing me a lot of trouble. I think I actually managed to fix the problem just now by adding the glext to my windows SDK using that code that I found on the registry.

Comment: If I was in this situation, the simplest solution for me would be to reformat and install Linux. Every Linux distribution includes the current version of opengl, together with a plethora of development tools, the current version of gcc, et. al., all configured and working.

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use glext.h. Use [GLEW](https://glew.sourceforge.net/) instead.

A long time ago (two decades maybe) for some reason operating systems stopped including up-to-date OpenGL headers. I suppose they did it this way so that graphics drivers could have newer OpenGL versions than the operating system. On Windows, it's the app's responsibility to include all the `#define` numbers itself, and use [`wglGetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress) to get the addresses of the functions.

Anyway, an up-to-date copy of GLEW knows all the up-to-date bits of OpenGL. (You may notice it was last updated in 2017 - so was OpenGL as the team moved on to Vulkan after that).